# using NSJSONSerialization in RubyMotion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I'm using RubyMotion and trying to serialize an object to json. I'm not getting an error message but this causes my app to crash.

```
  class Foo
     attr_accessor :name
  end

  e = Pointer.new(:object) 

  testItem = Foo.new              
  testItem.name = "test"          

  testJson = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(testItem, options:0, error: e)
```

Can anyone see if Im using this class correctly? (or know an alternative)

Comment: Where is `e` defined?

Comment: Thanks, I missed a line in the question. Updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your call.  The problem is with your data.  The top level object in your `testItem` must be an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary`.

You can use RubyMotion arrays and hashes since `Array < NSMutableArray < NSArray` and `Hash < NSMutableDictionary < NSDictionary`.

Try these sample testItems with your call:

```
testItem = ["test"]
testItem = {"names" => ["Fred", "Joe", "Mike"], "ages" => [17, 63, 28]}
```

From **NSJSONSerialization.h**:

> ```
> /* A class for converting JSON to Foundation objects and converting Foundation objects to JSON.
>
>    An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>     - Top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary
>     - All objects are NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull
>     - All dictionary keys are NSStrings
>     - NSNumbers are not NaN or infinity
> */
> ```

Comment: You're welcome.  I had to do a bit a research to answer that one.  I'd appreciate an up vote as well if you feel so inclined.